# How to use regex validator for phone numbers like 999-999-9999

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to make a regex pattern for phone numbers like this format : 999-999-9999

So I tried this expression :

```
\+\d(-\d{3}){2}-\d{4}
```

But the format works on numbers like : +1-999-999-9999

I would appreciate if someone help me modifying the pattern to make it match the format 999-999-9999 , which means I don't want the user to enter the + sign at first of the string

Thank you

Comment: How about: `if(phNumber.matches("\\d{3}[-]\\d{3}[-]\\d{4}")) { do whatever }`? Take a look [here](http://www.journaldev.com/641/regular-expression-phone-number-validation-in-java) for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `\+\d(-\d{3}){2}-\d{4}` you have tried explicitly says:

> A `+` followed by a single digit followed by a hyphen and 3 digits (two times) followed by 4 digits.

If you don't want the `+` and the first single digit, don't include those in your regular expression.

This expression `\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}` says:

> 3 digits followed by a hyphen followed by 3 digits followed by a hyphen followed by 4 digits.